# Filter strings.xml with gradle-android-plugin?

Tags: android, gradle

How would I filter my res/values/strings.xml file?

Something like:

```
<resources>
    <string name="version_name">${version}</string>
...
```

The `${version}` would be expanded to the value of `version` from the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With groovy closure, if you prefer without ant external:

```
filter {
    line -> line.replace('${version}', version)
}
```

Comment: in my build.gradle where do I write the above code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReplaceTokens with filter method if you have your token in the following format: `@token@`

So if your file looks like this:

```
<resources>
   <string name="version_name">@version@</string>
...
```

then you can do:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

def version = '1.0'

processResources{
 filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['version': version])
}
```

You can do this for any task that supports filter methods (which looks like any task that extends `AbstractCopyTask`).

I am not sure how you do it if you want to keep the `${token}` format. You might be able to use a different filter or set the filter on ReplaceTokens. Looks like in ant you could set the begin and end tokens.