# How to replace a string for a buildvariant with gradle in android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have two flavors of my project:

```
flavor1 -> packagename: com.example.flavor1 
flavor2 -> packagename: com.example.flavor2
```

Now I want to build a buildvariant of flavor1 and flavor2. 
The only difference of the buildvariant is another packagename.

My project uses MapFragments and has just one Manifest - so I put the the permission name of MAPS_RECEIVE in my string resource files of the respective flavors.

The question is: how can I replace a string resource of a buildvariant?

I tried the following approach ([described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090304/filter-strings-xml-with-gradle-android-plugin)):

```
buildTypes{
    flavor1Rev{
        packageName 'com.example.rev.flavor1'
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['package_permission' : 'com.example.rev.flavor1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE'])
    }
}
```

But using this I got this error:

> Could not find method filter() for arguments
>   [{tokens={package_permission=com.example.rev.flavor1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE}},
>   BuildTypeDsl_D ecorated{name=ReplaceTokens, debuggable=false,
>   jniDebugBuild=false, renderscript DebugBuild=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, packageNameSuffix=null, versionNameS
>   uffix=null, runProguard=false, zipAlign=true, signingConfig=null}] on
>   BuildTypeD sl_Decorated{name=buderusFinal, debuggable=false,
>   jniDebugBuild=false, renderscr iptDebugBuild=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, packageNameSuffix=null, versionNa
>   meSuffix=null, runProguard=false, zipAlign=true, signingConfig=null}.

Do I have to define an own task for the filter method?

**EDIT [2013_07_09]:**

String in src/flavor1/res:

```
<string name="package_permission">package_permission</string>
```

Code in build.gradle to replace the string:

```
buildTypes{
    flavor1Rev{
        copy{
            from('src/res/'){
                include '**/*.xml'
                 filter{String line -> line.replaceAll(package_permission, 'com.example.rev.flavor1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE')}
            }
            into '$buildDir/res'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried another solution. But it doesn't work. Though the build is successfull but the string is not replaced. Can anyone give me a hint what's wrong with my copy task?

Comment: what about the new Manifest Merger? can this work for you? http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own, so here is the solution "step by step" - perhaps it will help some other newbies to gradle :)

- Copy Task in General:

  ```
  copy{
      from("pathToMyFolder"){
          include "my.file"
      }
      // you have to use a new path for youre modified file
      into("pathToFolderWhereToCopyMyNewFile")
  }
  ```
- Replace a line in General:

  ```
  copy {
     ...
     filter{
         String line -> line.replaceAll("<complete line of regular expression>",
                                        "<complete line of modified expression>")
     }
  }
  ```
- I think the biggest problem was to get the right paths, because I had to make this dynamically ([this link was very helpful for me](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/gradle$20set$20string/adt-dev/8igxEyihIlc/gk4b8K6ZxNYJ)). I solved my problem by replacing the special lines in the manifest and not in the String-file.
- The following example shows how to replace the "meta-data"-tag in the manifest to use youre google-maps-api-key (in my case there are different flavors that use different keys ):

  ```
  android.applicationVariants.each{ variant -> 
      variant.processManifest.doLast{ 
          copy{
              from("${buildDir}/manifests"){
                  include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
              }
              into("${buildDir}/manifests/$variant.name")

              // define a variable for your key:
              def gmaps_key = "<your-key>"

              filter{
                  String line -> line.replaceAll("<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY\" android:value=\"\"/>",
                                                 "<meta-data android:name=\"com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY\" android:value=\"" + gmaps_key + "\"/>")
              }

              // set the path to the modified Manifest:
              variant.processResources.manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/manifests/${variant.name}/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml")
          }    
     }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 12):

I use almost exactly the approach you wanted to. The `replaceInManfest` is also generic and can be used for other placeholders as well. The `getGMapsKey()` method just returns the appropriate key based on the buildType.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildType = variant.buildType
    variant.processManifest.doLast {
        replaceInManifest(variant,
            'GMAPS_KEY',
            getGMapsKey(buildType))
    }
}

def replaceInManifest(variant, fromString, toString) {
    def flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0)
    def buildtype = variant.buildType
    def manifestFile = "$buildDir/manifests/${flavor.name}/${buildtype.name}/AndroidManifest.xml"
    def updatedContent = new File(manifestFile).getText('UTF-8').replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    new File(manifestFile).write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
}
```

I have it up on a [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/saadfarooq/9651367) too if you want to see if it evolves later.

I found this to be a more elegant and generalizable approach than the others (although the token replacement just working would have been nicer).

Answer (score 4):

The answers are quite outdated, there are better ways now to archive it. You can use the command in your build.gradle:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
            myPlaceholder: "placeholder",
    ]
```

and in your manifest:

```
android:someManifestAttribute="${myPlaceholder}"
```

more information can be found here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Answer (score 0):

In the current Android Gradle DSL, the `ApplicationVariant` class has changed and Saad's approach has to be rewritten e.g. as follows:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.processManifest.doLast {
            replaceInManifest(output,
                    'GMAPS_KEY',
                    getGmapsKey(buildType))

            }
        }
    }

def replaceInManifest(output, fromString, toString) {
    def updatedContent = output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile.getText('UTF-8')
        .replaceAll(fromString, toString)
    output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile.write(updatedContent, 'UTF-8')
}
```

The new DSL also offers a cleaner approach to get directly to the manifest file.