# Imported Eclipse project - Gradle buildTypes with different AndroidManifests

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio

I'm unable to create two different build types that use different manifests. Even after re-running gradle with --rerun-tasks and deleting the build directory entirely, the AndroidManifest being included in the apk is incorrect. For example, I run assembleRelease and it's including the AndroidManifest from the ReleasePlus build type. I would like to keep the project structure as-is without having to switch to the new src//* structure. I've also tried using product flavors but that doesn't seem to be a possibility without changing the structure.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    signingConfigs {
        myConfig {
            storeFile file("app.keystore")
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard.flags'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
            buildConfig 'public final static boolean PLUS = false; public final static String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.app.settings";'
        }
        debug {
            buildConfig 'public final static boolean PLUS = false; public final static String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.app.settings";'
        }
        debugPlus.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        debugPlus {
            packageNameSuffix '.plus'
            buildConfig 'public final static boolean PLUS = true; public final static String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.app.plus.settings";'
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifestPlus.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src', 'src-plus']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-plus']
                }
                debugPlus.setRoot('build-types/debugPlus')
            }
        }
        releasePlus.initWith(buildTypes.release)
        releasePlus {
            packageNameSuffix '.plus'
            buildConfig 'public final static boolean PLUS = true; public final static String PROVIDER_AUTHORITY = "com.app.plus.settings";'
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifestPlus.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src', 'src-plus']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-plus']
                }
                releasePlus.setRoot('build-types/releasePlus')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next structure:

```
android {

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        debug {
            manifest.srcFile 'debug/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

        release {
            manifest.srcFile 'release/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that gradle will try to merge your manifests into one, but it is not as powered as git, so most likely you will need to copy-paste whole file. It is ok for 2, but should be considered as bad practice. You can learn how to automate changes at AndroidManifest from this answer: [Replacing a string in AndroidManifest.xml for a buildvariant doesn't work for Gradle Android Plugin Version > 0.5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358408/replacing-a-string-in-androidmanifest-xml-for-a-buildvariant-doesnt-work-for-gr)