# resValue gradle error: Unsupported type "String" in "generated.xml"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

A few weeks ago I posted a question [How to override resources depending on buildType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159484/override-resources-with-gradle-depending-on-buildtype).
And just yesterday there was a [gradle plugin release for android](https://plus.google.com/109385828142935151413/posts/UVKA58MZV3J).
Based on [this post on G+](https://plus.google.com/102464608611447522943/posts/FseAYeAJx9x) I decided to write this question.

**The problem I have described in detail:**

I want to create some resource values depending on the `buildType`, but this doesn't work properly:
The file "generated.xml" will be only created if I make a complete build over the command line:

```
gradlew build
```

But I also get an error by building the complete project over comannd line:

```
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:merge<buildVariant>Resources'.
Unsupported type 'String' in file C:\Users\...\build\res\generated\release\values\generated.xml
```

Every other build-trial doesn't create this file. I tried following:

- over IDE:

  - rebuild project
  - execute external task "assembleBuildVariant"
- over command line:

  - gradlew assembleBuildVariant

Strange gradle console output:

```
:app:generateBuildVariantResValues UP-TO-DATE
```

**My build.gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO DEBUG\""
        resValue "String", "RES FOO", "RES FOO DEBUG"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO RELEASE\""
        resValue "String", "RES FOO", "RES FOO RELEASE"
    }
}
```

**My "generated.xml":**

```
<!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->

<!-- Values from build type: release -->
<item name="RES FOO" type="String">RES FOO RELEASE</item>
```

**My question:**

Is this a bug or did I miss something? And why this file isn't created by a `Rebuild` over the IDE?

**My build.gradle (UPDATE 2014-02-10 based on rciovatis answer):**

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO"
}

buildTypes {
    debug{
        buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO DEBUG\""
        resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO DEBUG"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO RELEASE\""
        resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO RELEASE"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2014-02-14 IT WORKS:**

After [an update of the gradle android plugin](https://plus.google.com/109385828142935151413/posts/KSSNex5STLA) everything works fine:

In /build/res/all/ you should see following folders:

- all
- generated (-> here you find the generated resource values by `resValue`)

The first folder `all` contains all merged resources. In the direction `all/<buildVariant>/values/values.xml` you should find the generated resources, in my case:

```
// for buildType DEBUG
<item name="TESTFOO" type="string">TEST FOO DEBUG</item>
// for buildType RELEASE
<item name="TESTFOO" type="string">TEST FOO RELEASE</item>
```

To get the values in code just use the generated resource like all others:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.TESTFOO)
```

Comment: Why do you need **buildConfigField**?  Where are you calling it in your code?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I solved adding the resources also in the `defaultConfig` block. For you it would be something like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO RELEASE"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug{
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO DEBUG\""
            resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO DEBUG"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "FOO", "\"FOO RELEASE\""
            resValue "string", "RES_FOO", "RES FOO RELEASE"
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that:

- item type must be `string` and not `String`
- item name must not contain spaces (as normal resource name)

EDIT:
Since 0.8.3 it should works fine just declaring the resValue in the build type block.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It makes really sense that the item name shouldn't contain spaces :). I tried your answer (see my update), but I still haven't access to the new resource value from the code (-> `getResources().getString(R.string.RES_FOO)`). Also the file "generated.xml" isn't created by a build over the IDE. In the gradle console I can see the task for `resValue`, but it's always UP-TO-DATE (:app:generate<buildVariant>ResValues UP-TO-DATE). Do you have access to the generated res values from code?

Comment: With the latest version of the gradle plugin (-> 0.8.3) it works fine.

Comment: As of today another solution is to create src/debug/res/values/strings.xml and add the RES_FOO string in there. In this case I'm assuming the RES_FOO in your default strings.xml is what will be used for release builds, but if that's not the case you can create a src/release/res/values/strings.xml also.

Comment: Note: use quotes when adding a long number as string resource, or it will be treated as integer anyway. 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78839

Comment: How can we define string array in the gradle file for a particular flavor or build type?

Comment: I would upvote again if I could! This saves me so much time and headache!

Comment: @AnkitGarg, there is a way, If you want array in BuildConfig - it;s simple. If you want it in res, you could try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655569/3212712

Comment: The strings I had were suddenly gone as well. Putting them in the defaultConfig fixed it for me as well.