# Change apk name with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project which uses Gradle for build process. Now I want to add two extra build types staging and production, so my build.gradle contains:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }

        staging {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.staging

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig)
            }
        }

        production {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.production
        }
    }
}
```

and my appndVersionNameVersionCode looks like:

```
def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
    if(variant.zipAlign) {
        def file = variant.outputFile
        def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
        variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }

    def file = variant.packageApplication.outputFile
    def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
    variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
}
```

If I execute task *assembleStaging* then I get proper name of my apk, but when I execute *assembleProduction* then I get changed names of my apk (like in staging case). For example:

```
MyApp-defaultFlavor-production-9.9.9-999.apk
MyApp-defaultFlavor-production-9.9.9-999.apk
```

It looks like in production build type is executed *appendVersionNameVersionCode*. How can I avoid it?

Comment: I suspect that you do not want to be iterating over `applicationVariants`, but rather only those variants tied to `staging`. I am not sufficiently familiar with the Gradle for Android object model to tell you specifically what you would use, though.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As CommonsWare wrote in his comment, you should call `appendVersionNameVersionCode` only for staging variants. You can easily do that, just slightly modify your `appendVersionNameVersionCode` method, for example:

```
def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
    //check if staging variant
    if(variant.name == android.buildTypes.staging.name){
        if(variant.zipAlign) {
            def file = variant.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
            variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }

    def file = variant.packageApplication.outputFile
    def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
    variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I've only introduced small modification to the condition. Now it looks like: if(variant.buildType.name == android.buildTypes.staging.name).

Answer (score 20):

Lecho's solution doesn't work for Android Gradle Plugin 0.14.3+ because of removal of deprecated APIS:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

> Almost 1.0: removed deprecated properties/methods
>
> ...
>
> - Variant.packageApplication/zipAlign/createZipAlignTask/outputFile/processResources/processManifest (use the variant output)

The following works for me:

```
def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        if (output.zipAlign) {
            def file = output.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }

        def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
        def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + defaultConfig.versionCode + ".apk")
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Where did you find the documentation (or any hint/explication) for the new variant api (ie the outputs property)?

Comment: I googled it and came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997866/gradle-warning-variant-getoutputfile-and-variant-setoutputfile-are-deprecat/26297636#26297636 ;)

Comment: I have the latest gradle and android studio version but interestingly I get the error message "could not find property "outputs" when trying above snippet.

Comment: There was further changes in AS 1.1, you can find an updated script here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649240/build-release-apk-with-customize-name-format-in-android-studio

Comment: ugh - can someone please tell these developers to keep their APIs consistent for more than a few months!

Answer (score 5):

If you use Kotlin DSL, then here is how you can change the APK name:

```kotlin
    applicationVariants.all {
        outputs.all {
            this as com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl

            val buildName = buildType.name
            val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(Date())
            val apkName = timestamp + "_AppName_" + defaultConfig.versionName + "." + defaultConfig.versionCode + "_" + buildName + ".apk"

            outputFileName = apkName
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to use the timestamp, remove it. Otherwise, don't forget these lines on top of the file to import java classes:

```java
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

You can also compare the build name in order to specify a config for different builds, like so:

```
name == "debug"
/* or */
name.contains("release")
```

Answer (score 4):

### For newer android studio Gradle

**AppName** is your app name you want so replace it
**variantName** will be default Selected variant or flavor
**Date will Today's date**, So need to do any changes just paste it

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        def variantName = variant.name
        def versionName = variant.versionName
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd-MM-YYYY')
        outputFileName = "AppName_${variantName}_D_${formattedDate}_V_${versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

### Output:

**AppName_release_D_26-04-2021_V_1.2.apk**

Answer (score 0):

I have use little generic version of it. build and install fine.
for example your projectName is "Salad" then for staging apk name will be "Salad-staging-dd-MM-YY" you can also change for debug and release apk. hope my solution will be better.

Change in `projectName/app/build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {

debug{

}

staging{
 debuggable true
 signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
 variant.outputs.each { output ->
 def date = new Date();
 def formattedDate = date.format('dd-MM-yyyy')
 def appName = getProjectDir().getParentFile().name
 output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                                output.outputFile.name.replace(getProjectDir().name +"-staging", "$appName-staging-" + formattedDate)
                                //for Debug use output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                                //                             output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "-" + formattedDate)
                        )
  }
 }
}

release {
  minifyEnabled false
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

to change Android app name [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600160/resvalue-gradle-error-unsupported-type-string-in-generated-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done:

```
 def appName
        if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
            appName = applicationName
        } else {
            appName = parent.name
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace("app-release.apk", appName + "_V" + versionCode + ".apk"))
            }
        }
```

Comment: Deprecated in newest Gradle... [4]

Answer (score 0):

i successfully create apk in android studio 4.1v or above.
application level gradle
Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    ext.play_services_version = '16.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


//..............and another module level gradle within........//
buildTypes{
release {

            def versionCode = "4.1.0"

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all() { output ->
                    variant.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
                        def appName = "MyAPP" + versionCode + ".apk"
                        outputFileName = new File("./build/",
                                appName.replace(".apk", "_${flavor.name}.apk")
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
           // ext.enableCrashlytics = false
           // ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using gradle 7.5 
my version of the filename consists in :

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        println("Generating variant: " + variant.getName())
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def variantName = variant.name
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def formattedDate = new Date().format('dd_MM_YY')
            output.versionCodeOverride = defaultConfig.versionCode * 10 + variant.productFlavors.get(0).abiVersionCode
            //output.outputFileName = "${defaultConfig.applicationId}.${variantName}_v${versionName}_${defaultConfig.versionCode}.apk"
            output.outputFileName = "${variantName}_v${versionName}_${defaultConfig.versionCode}_${formattedDate}.apk"
        }
    }
```