# Build release apk with customize name format in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want the `.apk` to be built with the following name format (with timestamp).

How can I set it?

format : `{app_name}{yyyymmddhis}.apk`

Now, it is fixed with the name `{app_name}-{release}.apk`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

in the `build.gradle` file, you should change/add `buildTypes` like this:

```
buildTypes {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def file = variant.outputFile
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
            variant.outputFile = new File(
                                    file.parent, 
                                    file.name.replace("-release", "-" + formattedDate)
                                    )
        }
    }       
}
```

====== EDIT with Android Studio 1.0 ======

If you are using Android Studio 1.0, you will get an error like this:

```
Error:(78, 0) Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@67e7625f.
```

You should change the `build.Types` part to this:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    def date = new Date();
                    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, 
                                            output.outputFile.name.replace("-release", "-" + formattedDate)
                                            )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any good tutorial website of how to use gradle can be provided :) ?

Comment: @LoGary http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide This is a good site to begin with. And you can always search on StackOverflow

Answer (score 9):

As a side note, I would really like to know where people get the objects structures of gradle build objects.

To construct this I've used some trial and errors, a bit of Googling, and [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) (which is out of date)

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def flavor = "default";
                if (variant.productFlavors.size() > 0)
                    flavor = variant.productFlavors.get(0);

                def initials = "DefaultFlavor";
                if (flavor.name == "flavor1")
                    initials = "F1";
                else if (flavor.name == "flavor2")
                    initials = "F2";

                def build = "Debug";
                if (variant.buildType.name == "release")
                    build = "Release"
                def finalName = variant.versionCode + "-" + initials + "-" + build + "-v" + flavor.versionName + "-MyAppName.apk";
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, finalName)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Ok, So as a side note, if you would like to determine the names of your libs project here is a quick script, make sure you put it in each of your library gradle build files.

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.4"
        project.version = versionName
    }

    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-v${version}.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change something like this. Doing dynamically.

`project.archivesBaseName = {app_name}{yyyymmddhis};`

But I have read that this is going to be deprecated.

Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Deprecated dynamic property: "archivesBaseName" on "root project 'myapp'", value: "AnotherName".