# Gradle warning: variant.getOutputFile() and variant.setOutputFile() are deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, deprecation-warning

I am using the following simplified configuration in an Android application project.

```groovy
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def file = variant.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + versionName + ".apk")
            variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }
    }    
}
```

Now that I updated the Gradle plug-in to v.0.13.0 and Gradle to v.2.1. the following warnings appear:

```java
WARNING [Project: :MyApp] variant.getOutputFile() is deprecated. 
    Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
WARNING [Project: :MyApp] variant.setOutputFile() is deprecated. 
    Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
WARNING [Project: :MyApp] variant.getOutputFile() is deprecated. 
    Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
WARNING [Project: :MyApp] variant.setOutputFile() is deprecated. 
    Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
```

How can I rewrite the Groovy script to get rid of the deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Building on the answer from [Larry Schiefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25999264/503668) you can change the script to something like this:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def fileName = outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried running this code?  I get `Could not find property 'file' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@4b50996.`  This android gradle plugin is brutal.

Comment: @Merk Actually, yes, I came here looking for an answer to the same question, and finally managed to get it working with the snippet above (although I've got some slightly different code inside the if).
Sounds like you've written something wrong if you cannot find the property 'file', since no such property is used in my snippet :)

Comment: Puzzling because this is the offending line:  `output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "AppName_playstorebuild.apk")`.  BTW I am using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'`

Comment: @Merk And did you include the two lines before it? Without `def file = output.outputFile` the property 'file' will obviously not exist.

Comment: From my testing, `output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)` appears to still cause this warning to be thrown. Started a separate question thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688660/variant-getoutputfile-is-deprecated-call-it-on-one-of-variant-getoutputs-in)

Comment: I'm having an error. Apk's name and what Android Studio is looking for in the local path isn't the same. I've posted something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082087/gradle-autoincrement-and-rename-apk-i-o-error

Comment: I am getting this error on M1 MBP: `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'`. Target API 30, Gradle plugin 4.2.2 Gradle versin 6.9.

Answer (score 16):

The complete code snippet looks like that one:

```
// Customize generated apk's name with version number
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def outputFile = output.outputFile
        if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def manifestParser = new com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser()
            def fileName = outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-DEBUG-" + manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile) + ".apk")
            output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The build variant output API has changed in the latest Android Gradle plugin.  It now allows multiple output files (or directories), which is why this method has been marked as deprecated.  If you use `variant.outputs` instead, it will give you a `Collection` you can then iterate over and get each output file.  You'll have to verify the file object is non-null and that it matches your criteria (e.g. has a '.apk' extension.)  Then you can create a new `File` object and add it to the output within the collection.

Comment: Neither `variant.outputs.outputFile.name = "NewBuildName.apk"` nor            `variant.outputs.add(new File("NewBuildName.apk"))` has any effect, so I'm not sure what action you're suggesting.

Comment: Where is the documentation to see what properties are in the "output" object?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point in time this is largely undocumented. You have to rely on in-line help within Android Studio (not very useful) or go digging through Groovy/Java code within the plugin itself to find the details.  Since `outputs` is a `Collection` you should be able to find docs on the Groovy/Java `Collection` object.

Answer (score 4):

Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0

You can use like this

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

you can get more on the features and new changes in android documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle