# Change outputfile using new 'outputs' property in 0.13.0

Tags: android, gradle

Just updated my android project to latest android gradle plugin and changed the script since there are some deprecated methods. However, I got `argument type mismatch` error when I tried to build the project. I found that something was wrong when I tried to change the `outputfile` name, the following is part of script in 'build.gradle':

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

   def apkName = target;
   if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
      apkName += "-RELEASE.apk";
   } else {
      apkName += "-DEBUG.apk"
   }

   // this is the line caused type mismatch error
   variant.outputs.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/apk/" + apkName)
}
```

I tried to changed to 
     `variant.outputs.outputFile = "$project.buildDir/outputs/apk/" + apkName`
but it's not working.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing my own answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297636/503668) you can change the script to something like this:

```
variant.outputs.each { output ->
    if (output.outputFile != null && output.outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
        output.outputFile = file("${project.buildDir}/outputs/apk/" + apkName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to set the `outputFile` property directly on the variant.

```
variant.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/apk/" + apkName)
```

Comment: The question specifically states that he uses a version of the android gradle plugin where variant.outputFile is deprecated.