# variant.getOutputFile() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This has been coming up since the bump to gradle 2.1 in Android Gradle plugin 0.13.0, but for the life of me I can't understand why logs this warning sometimes.

Consider this block for renaming APKs based on variant type:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def oldFile = output.outputFile
        if (oldFile != null && oldFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
            def newFile = "Fancy conditionally-formatted file name here"
            print "\nBefore"
            output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)
            print "\nAfter"
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the gradle logs, I see this:

```
Before
WARNING [Project: <myproject>] variant.getOutputFile() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
WARNING [Project: <myproject>] variant.getProcessResources() is deprecated. Call it on one of variant.getOutputs() instead.
After
```

Which would *seem* to suggest that calling the line `output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)` throws this warning. Thing is, Google specifically uses this style in their example at the bottom of [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-Variant-API-Version-Code-support). If we can't touch `output` at all, how can we set its `outputFile`?

On top of this, I don't see how `getProcessResources()` is involved.

Any ideas?

Comment: The message seems to suggest to use `variant.getOutputs().getOutputFile()` instead of `variant.getOutputFile()`. I'd consider it more likely that the message appeared after bumping the Gradle Android plugin version, rather than the Gradle version (although I can't tell for sure).

Comment: It did start after bumping the android gradle plugin to 0.13, sorry I should've specified that. That said, your comment doesn't really solve the problem :/. `variant.getOutputs().getOutputFile()` isn't a legal call

Comment: OK, then the message probably suggests to use `variant.getOutputs[x].getOutputFile()` instead of `variant.getOutputFile()`, as done in the snippet above. Perhaps the new method is implemented in terms of the old, resulting in an unwarranted warning. If you want to dig deeper, I'd check the source code or ask on the Android tools list.

Comment: `variant.getOutputFile()` is never called in the above code. Any outputFile calls are already done within the loop over the outputs returned by `getOuputs()`

Comment: Is the above code the literal snippet that caused the mentioned warnings? If not, did you run this snippet to see if it caused the same warnings?
I cannot see anything wrong in the above code, and would have to suggest that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It's definitely in the above snippet, specifically the line `output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)`. The print statements on either side confirm this in the gradle log

Comment: The only way to be sure that `variant.getOutputFile()` is never called is to check the implementation of `output.setOutputFile()`. Anyway, the question is so specific that it's best directed to the developers of the code. Might just be a bug.

Comment: I tried looking for the implementation, but it doesn't appear to be open source (yet?). Looking around google code, all I can every find is gradle version properties. Do you have a link by chance?

Comment: I don't. Best contact the authors, e.g. on the Android tooling list. Also be aware that this is just a deprecation warning, which you could live with for now until the underlying problem is fixed (assuming it's a bug in the plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Gradle plugin was still using deprecated calls under the hood. As of Android Gradle Plugin 0.14.4, these warnings no longer appear.

Comment: You mean that upgrading to gradle 0.14.4 solved your problem of warning on the old variant.output call?

Comment: Yup. It was something being done in the plugin API, not directly my code.

Comment: Very strange, if i keep referring to variant.outputFile instead of variant.outputs.outputFile on the 0.14.4 I get an error. Only when you change it to the variant.outputs.outputFile

Comment: That makes sense. They've removed those methods in 0.14.4 in preparation for 1.0. What I was saying is that it was not my code that was throwing the warning, rather than the plugin itself was using deprecated calls under the hood.

Also `variant.outputs.outputFile` doesn't make sense. outputs is a collection

Answer (score 2):

Change `variant.outputFile` to `variant.outputs[x].outputFile`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
def newFile = "Fancy conditionally-formatted file name here"
output.outputFile = new File(oldFile.parent, newFile)
```

Do following

```
def apk = output.outputFile
def newName = getNewName() // any fancy formatted file name
apk.renameTo(new File(apk.parentFile, newName))
```

Hope it helps.