# Gradle Autoincrement and Rename APK I/O Error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm trying to do an auto increment for the build number in Android Studio. Followed this [link](http://andreborud.com/android-studio-automatic-incremental-gradle-versioning/), and it worksfine.

Now I want to rename the apk using the versionName. I also did that successfully, as I can see in my app\build\outputs\apk directory, that the file is there.

**The problem** The generated apk and the part where Android Studio you see the "local path" don't have the same file name.

The generated apk's name: MyAppsName-v1.0-64-debug.apk

The "local path" it's looking for: ..\app\build\outputs\apk\MyAppsName-v1.0-60-debug.apk

So it makes sense to see an error saying "Local path doesn't exist." Because the "MyAppsName-v1.0-60-debug.apk" does not exist.

Here's the snippet of my build.gradle:

```
 def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')

if (versionPropsFile.canRead()) {
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()

    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    def value = 0
    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
        value = 1;
    }

    def versionMajor = 1
    def versionMinor = 0
    def versionBuild = versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'].toInteger() + 1
    def version_Code = versionProps['VERSION_CODE'].toInteger() + value

    versionProps['VERSION_BUILD'] = versionBuild.toString()
    versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = version_Code.toString()

    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode version_Code
        versionName "v${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}-${versionBuild}"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }


    archivesBaseName = "MyAppsName" + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName;
} else {
    throw new GradleException("Could not read version.properties!")
}
```