# I keep getting this error while building an app using com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Here's the error:

```
    Error:No such property: packageApplicationTask for class:
    com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApkVariantOutputData
```

Here's my plugin list:

```
   apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
   apply plugin: 'hugo'
   apply plugin: 'com.trello.victor'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
   apply plugin: 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins.dexinfo'
   apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'
   apply plugin: 'com.mindera.gradle.slack'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   apply plugin: 'com.github.alexfu.androidautoversion'
   apply plugin: 'net.jokubasdargis.build-timer'
   apply plugin: 'hu.supercluster.paperwork'
   apply plugin: "build-time-tracker"
   apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
   apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
   apply plugin: "com.lib.logthisannotations"
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
   apply plugin: 'com.noveogroup.android.check'
   apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Answer (score 14):

My problem was Jrebel and Android Studio 2.2.
I have removed any references to jrebel in my gradle files and now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

just try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297636/1743786) by user [thorbear](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503668/thorbear)

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                def fileName = outputFile.name.replace('.apk', "-${versionName}.apk")
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```