# Generate apk name as package name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, package-name

Android studio will generate default apk name as app-(release|debug).apk.
How to generate apk file name same as package name of the app like `com.example-debug.apk`.

Comment: this link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126299/change-apk-name-with-gradle/22126638#22126638

Comment: The above link is useful

Answer (score 16):

You can do it without using another tasks, setting the `archivesBaseName`.

For example:

```
 defaultConfig {
      ....
      project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "MyName-" + defaultConfig.versionName);

  }
```

Output:

```
MyName-1.0.12-release.apk
```

In your case:

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "com.example" );
```

Comment: You might be able to access rootProject name and use it like this: `project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", rootProject.getName() + "-" + defaultConfig.versionName);`

Comment: unfortunately doesn't scale when you work with variants as archivesBaseName is global for all of them

Answer (score 4):

Try putting this in your module's build.gradle

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        def appId = android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        def fileName = appId + "-" variant.buildType.name +".apk"
        output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only spits out one APK for me and doesn't spit out an APK for each build variant.

Comment: Of course not, if you want apk for another variant, you have to change the build variant first. Or use a command to build all versions. This code only changes the name of the apk, nothing more.

Comment: using './gradlew assemble' in terminal should spit out all buildTypes of all variants. Otherwise you can do './gradlew assembleRelease' or './gradlew assembleDebug' for these specific buildTypes

Answer (score 2):

you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126299/change-apk-name-with-gradle/22126638#22126638).
or Illogical option to rename your `release|debug.apk` with name what you want in file browser.

this code may be useful for you:

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
            def newName = output.outputFile.name
            newName = newName.replace("app-", "$rootProject.ext.appName-") //"MyAppName" -> I set my app variables in the root project
            newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
        }
    }
}
    debug {
    }
}
```

enjoy your code:)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named customname.gradle in the top level directory of the project.Put this code into it.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->;
def appName
//Check if an applicationName property is supplied; if not use the name of the parent project.
if (project.hasProperty("applicationName")) {
    appName = applicationName
} else {
    appName = parent.name
}

variant.outputs.each { output ->;
    def newApkName
    //If there's no ZipAlign task it means that our artifact will be unaligned and we need to mark it as such.
    if (output.zipAlign) {
        newApkName = "${appName}-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    } else {
        newApkName = "${appName}-${output.baseName}-${variant.versionName}-unaligned.apk"
    }
    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
}}
```

Then in your app module's gradle add this code

```
apply from: "../customname.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. This code will create app name like `applicationId-release.apk` or `applicationId-debug.apk` in which applicationId can be your package name.

```
buildTypes {

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def newName = output.outputFile.name
            newName = newName.replace("app-", applicationId)
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
        }
    }
}
```