# How to change apk name by using gradle like this format?

Tags: android, gradle

I'd like to change "app-release.apk" file name to like following when I build an app by using gradle.

```
[format]
(appname of package name)_V(version code)_(yyMMdd)_(R|T)

[explain]
(appname of package name) : example) com.example.myApp -> myApp
(version code) : build version code 2.2.3 -> 223
(yyMMdd) : build date 2015.11.18 -> 151118  
(R|T) : if app is release, "R" but debug is "T".
```

If I generate an apk file in release, result is : myApp_V223_151118_R.apk.

How to make a file name like this in gradle?

Comment: Check my answer for Gradle latest versions (3.4 + ) 2019 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389583/1348522

Comment: Check this answer for new gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/67268901/8572350

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Update: Please check [Anrimian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969974/206292) below which is much simpler and shorter.**

Try this:

**gradle.properties**

```
applicationName = MyApp
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
     versionCode 111
     ...
  }
  buildTypes {
     release {
         ...
         applicationVariants.all { variant ->
             renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, 'R')
         }
     }
     debug {
         ...
         applicationVariants.all { variant ->
             renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, 'T')
         }
     }
  }
}
def renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, buildType) {
 variant.outputs.each { output ->
     def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyMMdd')

     def file = output.packageApplication.outputFile
     def fileName = applicationName + "_V" + defaultConfig.versionCode + "_" + formattedDate + "_" + buildType + ".apk"
     output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
 }
}
```

**Reference:** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30332234/206292
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27104634/206292

Comment: When I do the above, I get: app-development-release.apk, app-live-release.apk. Why is it saying "app" and not my app name?

Comment: @Subby make sure you have set your applicationName in gradle.properties.

Comment: applicationVariants.all should not be nested in each variant:

debug {}
release { }
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  renameAPK(variant, defaultConfig, variant.name)
}

Comment: How we can add architectures name to apk name? For exampe "MyApp_V223_151118_R_arm.apk" and  "MyApp_V223_151118_R_x86.apk"

Comment: @Krishnaraj are you sure this solution works with the latest gradle version? It turns out, whichever build you make, the renameAPK for buildtype which is at the bottom (debug inn this case) is called. Hence in our case   we will always have '_T' at the end.

Comment: @gaurav414u No, I am not using this solution. I wrote this answer in 2016 and things may have changed now :).

Comment: How would this be in Koltin DSL?

Answer (score 154):

This may be the shortest way:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    applicationId "com.blahblah.example"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")
}
```

buildType: like so

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        versionNameSuffix "-T"
    }
    release {
        ...
        versionNameSuffix "-R"
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, Android Studio adds versionNameSuffix by build type name by default, so you may not need this.

Upd. In new versions of Android Studio you can it write little shorter(thanks for [szx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249230/szx) comment):

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)"
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer of them all

Comment: The best answer with no doubts!

Comment: Looks like you have the versionCode and versionName swapped.

Comment: Can't find the sense of this line:     setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationId + "-v" + versionCode + "(" + versionName + ")")

What are you trying to do here?

Comment: In recent versions of gradle you can do the same with `archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)"` (reads better in my opinion)

Comment: this adds the suffix to the BuildConfig variable and sometimes is useful to display it on your app without the suffix. Not good for my use case

Comment: Also make sure that you put `archivesName` AFTER `versionName` setter.

Answer (score 43):

**2019 / 2020 - How to change APK name For Gradle 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 4.0 and above**

```
android {
   ......
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.all {
           def flavor = variant.name
           def versionName = variant.versionName
           outputFileName = "prefix_${flavor}_${versionName}.apk"
       }
   }
}
```

The result would be like this,

> prefix_release_1.0.1.apk

Comment: May or may not be the answer to this question, but it answered another question for me.  Thanks.