# Android: Library (AAR) module build.gradle coding

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have a project tree (a Solution in terms of Visual Studio) with some Executable and AAR library modules.

I need to get something like this in their build.gradle files..

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        //if not exist :- create extra folder in standard or customised output folder 
        //with the name 'Release'
        //say builder to put the release build version into this folder with
        //names ModuleName.aar or .apk
    }
    debug {
        //if not exist :- create extra folder in standard or customised output folder
        //with name 'Debug'
        //say builder to put the debug build version into this folder with
        //names ModuleName.aar or .apk
    }
}
```

I've spent 2 days looking for a documentation how to do that.. I found just fragmentary parts of some specific settings, which ain't interesting now.

Actually, I want to get the same behaiviour of the compiler and builder as it's in Visual Studio

> ProjectBuildDir\Debug\ModuleName.aar
>
> ProjectBuildDir\Release\ModuleName.aar

Please, if you know, this would be very good to share that knowledge..
Otherwise.. I think I'll spend whole week without success.. or refer to full documentation of how to program gradle build code.

UPD: I've seen [such kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775160/how-to-change-apk-name-by-using-gradle-like-this-format) of solution, but it makes my project structure unreadable by AS. It denies to sync project with its gradle.. it hides Tool window "Build variants".. it hangs on AS itself.. :)
Maybe it happens because it's applied to Module (AAR library)?
I don't know.. I just also unable to compile and build the release version :)
I can see debug but whem I change variamt in that Tool Window in front of the AAR-Module name - then run Rebuild (Clean and Sync..) - there is no any realease in the output folder.
And I can't find the description of this meta language..
I use the AAR as Android UserControl library - extended View.. because it's handy to develop it as separate module.. simply faster..
I am the Android-kid, but MicroSoft-man :) need to see the logic of the project meta data language..

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775160/how-to-change-apk-name-by-using-gradle-like-this-format

Comment: I tried that solution before, but it comes to another issue: Error: Could not find property 'applicationVariants' on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false,..............