# Renamed apk cant install through Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I rename my output apk file with gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent,
                        output.outputFile.name.replace("-debug", "-GGG-" + getDate())
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMddHHmm')
    return formattedDate
}
```

But i get error when try to install app to phone through Android Studio:

```
The APK file C:\...\app\build\outputs\apk\app-GGG-201604191416.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

However, file what should install named app-GGG-201604191431.apk. 
Why Android Studio try to install early apk, and how i can solve it?

Comment: Have you performed a full clean of the project + restart AS?

Comment: @Benoit yes, but this was not help me

Comment: @OvechkinPavel : did you get the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Hit the "Refresh all Gradle Projects" button in the Gradle pane and do a project clean.

Comment: i dont want to do it on each compile

Answer (score 0):

android studio's installation command is still referring to previous apk app-GGG-201604191416.apk but on assemble you generated an apk with different name app-GGG-201604191431.apk.
you are making the apk name prone to date-time. So the script which is run for installation is not taking that change.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249036/app-release-apk-how-to-change-this-default-generated-apk-name) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126299/change-apk-name-with-gradle)
Something similar is in those links that you can relate to get your problem solved.

Comment: do you have any idea, how apply changes?