# gradle - copy db keys with different values for debug vs release

Tags: android, gradle

--EDIT 2--

Wrong question to ask, it was based on mechanics of earlier solution derived using Ant's capabilities. With gradle providing direct access to flavors of Resource.String values depending on [build-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600160/resvalue-gradle-error-unsupported-type-string-in-generated-xml) , question should have been

" How to provide diff values for resource-api-key values depending on build type ?"

The copy using tokens approach may work in ant but seems way off base in a gradle environment.

--Resolved with gradle only approach , not re-implement the 'ant approach'

put keys into config file...

```
configDbApi=..ovv
configDbRest=..eoj
configDbApiProd=..prd
configDbRestProd=..prdrest
```

tweek [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600160/resvalue-gradle-error-unsupported-type-string-in-generated-xml) in 'build.gradle' types...

```
    defaultConfig {        
     resValue "string", "db_app_id", configDbApiProd
         resValue "string", "db_rest_api_key", configDbRestProd
    }


    buildTypes {

        release {

            buildConfigField "String", "DBAPP", "\"DB APP RELEASE\""
            resValue "string", "db_app_id", configDbApiProd
            buildConfigField "String", "DBREST", "\"DB REST RELEASE\""
            resValue "string", "db_rest_api_key", configDbRestProd          
        } 
   debug{ copy it,pointing to diff config prop values for $debug}
    }
```

--Resolved end

--OP--

I have strings xml with tokens:

```
<string name="db_app_id">@configApi@</string>
<string name="db_rest_api_key">@configRest@</string>
```

While in `build.type=release`, I'd like to copy the prod db values from `gradle.properties`

```
configDbApiProd=....ovv
configDbRestProd=....heoj
```

So, there's a `copy` task that I'd to run somewhere within the stack of 'assembleRelease' tasks.

```
task copyStrings(type: Copy) {
  from('config') {
    include 'strings.xml'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [configApi: configDbApiProd, configRest: configDbRestProd])
}
    into 'res/values'
    }
```

...

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
//        generateReleaseBuildConfig.doFirst { copyStrings }
            runProguard true
            proguardFile 'proguard-android-optimize.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

My question is how to invoke this task as part of the assembleRelease stack?

```
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:compileReleaseJava
:lintVitalRelease
```

It seems like the copy should run before OR after `generateReleaseBuildConfig`
but I can not get the task `copyStrings` to invoke.

I will also want to do an analogous copy during `assembleDebug` step where I use different property values from `gradle.properties` for the dev DB keys.

--EDIT-- 
change the build.gradle and the task (copyStrings) not running before 'assembleDebug'...

```
tasks.assembleRelease.dependsOn(copyStrings)
```

expected result : copyStrings runs before assembleRelease

actual result : assembleRelease gets called without any call on task=copyStrings

Comment: added dependency of 'assembleRelease' on my task 'copyStrings' and my task does not get called

Answer (score 1):

What You need to do is to create dependency on the tasks using `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter`.

```
generateReleaseBuildConfig.dependsOn(copyStrings)
```

`dependsOn` is used to make a fixed dependency between tasks. When `A` task depends on `B` task, `B` will run before `A` (if it isn't up-to-date). `mustRunAfter` works a bit different. I doesn't force a task to be run, but when `A` must run after `B`, and both tasks are added to gradle invocation graph it's guaranteed that `B` will run first.