# How to use in a library a resource provided by the app that use the library

Tags: android

I am developping an Android HCE payment SDK and I would like to include the manifest part related to the APDU service in my SDK which will be provided as an Android library (AAR) to our clients.

```
    <!-- service -->
    <service
        android:name="com.mypackage.MyApduService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>
```

The problem is that the apduservice.xml cannot be defined in my library because it contains the payment service description and banner that should be customized by my clients when they build their payment app on top of my SDK.
Is there a way to tell my library manifest to get its android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service resource not in the library but somewhere else (somewhere being provided later by the payment app developer) ?
An other solution whould be to include the apduservice.xml in my SDK but I will have the same externalisation issue with the apduServiceBanner and description resources of this file: I will need a way to tell that these resources will be provided outside of the library by the payment app developper.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: this is a generic config(string) issue faced by anyone using a 3rd party lib within saas architecture , most notably in the database.. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/wiki/Login-Library  "running sample projects" for DB config in ./res/strings  and , for using variables that lib users can set after git/clone ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193910/gradle-copy-db-keys-with-different-values-for-debug-vs-release  ;; use strings to pt at uri's for resources

Comment: Thanks Robert Rowntree