# Android. Gradle. How to get flavor property in task

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build, task

I have an Android Gradle project with several flavors (different styles of the same app). I have a task that downloads some external file and puts it into assets folder. I need to specify an array of strings as a part of each flavor that (urls or filenames) that will be downloaded during the build of a specific flavor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316564/is-it-possible-to-define-an-android-string-array-resource-in-gradle

Answer (score 0):

````
```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
                    variant.outputs.all {
                        def currentProductFlavor = variant.productFlavors.name.get(0)
                        def apkName = rootProject.ext.app.appName + currentProductFlavor + "_" + rootProject.ext.app.appVersionName + ".apk"
                        println("======apkName:" + apkName)
                        outputFileName = apkName
                    }
                }
            }
```
````

Comment: Thanks. But the question is not how to get flavor name. But a flavor specific custom property value