# I'm migrating a Maven WAR build over to Gradle. How do I get the filters block to behave in the same way?

Tags: maven, gradle, war

I'm converting a build from Maven to Gradle, and in it, we do some resource filtering.  Specifically, we have a block that looks like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <filters>
        <filter>/path/to/more/resources.properties</filter>
        <filter>/path/to/more/resources.properties</filter>
        <filter>/path/to/more/resources.properties</filter>
    </filters>
</build>
```

...and we want to get something similar in Gradle.

The documentation for [the Copy tasks with filter in them](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) aren't that complete and don't describe what specific problem(s) I'm attempting to solve:

- Filtering out specific resource files
- Keeping the POM style of variables in use (`${example.property}`)
- Ensuring that the artifact makes its way into my WAR

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an expansion of [this Gradle-oriented answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475075/1079354) with some more concrete examples.

First, we need to read in all of the resources we care about into something that the `filter` method of the Copy task will recognize.  Conventionally, this has been just a standard `Properties` object.

That can be accomplished like so:

```
def resources = new Properties()
file($projectDir/src/main/resources/<insert-properties-file>.properties").withInputStream {
    resources.load(it)
}
```

Note that there may be a more elegant way to get more than one properties file in at once; this approach simply worked for me for a *single* file.

Next, we then need to actually do the filtering.  That can be accomplished with the `from` closure.  We leverage the [ReplaceTokens class](https://ant.apache.org/manual-1.9.x/api/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/ReplaceTokens.html) (which we can import) to do this, and configure the begin and end tokens to match our variable use.

```
from("$projectDir/path/to/folder/that/has/tokens/to/replace") {
    include "**/files-to-filter-on"
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: resources, beginToken: "${", endToken: "}")
}
```

To get that into the WAR, we need to load that into the `processResources` task.

All together:

```
processResources {
    with copySpec {
        def resources = new Properties()
        file($projectDir/src/main/resources/<insert-properties-file>.properties").withInputStream {
        resources.load(it)
    }

    from("$projectDir/path/to/folder/that/has/tokens/to/replace") {
        include "**/files-to-filter-on"
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: resources, beginToken: "${", endToken: "}")
    }
}
```

When you execute `./gradlew clean war`, the resources you want to have filtered will be correctly filtered in the archive.