# Gradle task replace string in .java file not working

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I've below `VersionConstants.java` file..

```
public class VersionConstants {

    /**
     * This class does not need to be instantiated.
     */
    private VersionConstants() { }


    public static final String VERSION = "@VERSION@";

    public static final String PATCH_LEVEL = "@PATCH_LEVEL@";

    public static final String REVISION = "@REVISION@";

    public static final String BUILDTIME = "@BUILDTIME@";

    public static final String BUILDHOST = "@BUILDHOST@";
}
```

I followed this answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475075/1665592 and tried as

```
task generateSources(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/replaceme/VersionConstants.java'
    into "$buildDir/generated-src"
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        "@VERSION@" : '1.0.0', 
        "@PATCH_LEVEL@" : '0.5',
        ...
    ])
}
```

but, it is coping `VersionConstants.java` file as it is and not replacing the keywords with desired values i.e. `1.0.0` or `0.5` etc.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I just replaced `@VERSION@` with `VERSION` and it work like a charm!

```
task generateSources(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/replaceme/VersionConstants.java'
    into "$buildDir/generated-src"
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        "VERSION" : '1.0.0', 
        "PATCH_LEVEL" : '0.5',
        ...
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, ReplaceTokens has beginToken='@' and endToken='@'. So change to

```
filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
        "VERSION" : '1.0.0', 
        "PATCH_LEVEL" : '0.5',
        ...
    ])
```